# setting the width of ng-bootstrap carousel

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I'm using ng-bootstrap to create a carousel for my angular project. I have succeeded in following the example shown at https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples and now have a carousel in the middle of the screen.

I now want the carousel to take up the entire width of the screen, instead of just sitting in the middle. How do I do this?

I have tried adding a class to the carousel and changing the width as such:

component HTML

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images" class="myclass">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

component css

```
.myclass{
   width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add direct in your html tag here example:

```
<img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide" class="mh-100" style="width: 100%; height: 50vh">
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set you `myclass` to your images. You are using bootstrap so you can use `w-100` instead:

[Try it online!](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jxhrm2-z4k8x6?file=app/carousel-basic.html)

```
<ngb-carousel *ngIf="images">
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide" class="w-100">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>First slide label</h3>
      <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[1]" alt="Random second slide" class="w-100">
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Second slide label</h3>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
  <ng-template ngbSlide>
    <img [src]="images[2]" alt="Random third slide" >
    <div class="carousel-caption">
      <h3>Third slide label</h3>
      <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
    </div>
  </ng-template>
</ngb-carousel>
```

You may also want to use `object-fit:cover;`

Comment: class="w-100" makes the image fill up the entire screen though. Is there a way to use it to control the height too?

Comment: 100% height or fix height?

Comment: I just want to fix the height to like 500px or something like that

Answer (score 0):

You could do that too. Instead of using w-100 using !Important

`<img [src]="images[0]" alt="Random first slide" width="100%">`